# Multiple Drop Down Selections with MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i want to display multiple drop downs.

if users selects TOUCH in 1st drop-down then second drop down should display 12MP and 17MP

if user selects Keypad in 1st drop down then then second drop down should display 16MP and 19MP

...

the php code which i'm using is only displaying one drop down. kindle please help me in solving this...

**MySQL - Table**

```
id   Name         Feature       Camera
1  Samsung       Touch          12MP
2  Nokia         Touch          17MP
3  LG            Multi-Touch    16MP
4  Apple         Keypad         16MP
5  Sony          Keypad         19MP
6  Onida         Keypad+Touch   17MP
7  HTC           Keypad+Touch   15MP
8  Black Berry   Multi-Touch    15MP
```

Thank you!!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)  Are you wanting to populate the second dropdown on a page reload (php), or without page reload (javascript/ajax)? have you tried searching Stackoverflow, as there are tons of examples - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dynamic+dropdown / http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dropdown+using+ajax

Comment: @Sean thanks for the comment. yes i have already searched stactoverflow. but they didn't met my requirement :( yes i'm looking to populate the second drop down  without page reload. will you kindle please help me regarding this..

Answer (score 1):

Well this topic is available in many sites and forums and the codes are even available to download..
But in general, you need to need to send the value of the first dropdown to a controller(frameworks) or any PHP file to process it and query the details form the database. and propulate/create the next dropdown with the queried data!
and for all of these you better use ajax. Jquery has a very nice and easy to use ajax function that you can be used to do all above!
have a look here: 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/